# htaccess rewriterule for grabbing everything past hostname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want an htaccess rewrite rule to grab everything past the host name and use it as an argument. For example, I want http://example.com/one to be handled by http://example.com/category.php?cat=one

I think it should be simple, but I can't quite find the combination.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^\./]*)[:;,\.]*$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,NS]
```

Anybody see any way to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ category.php?cat=$0 [B]
```

If you want to pass the query string along too, be sure to change the `B` flag to `B,QSA`, but be aware that someone could then pass the GET argument `cat`, which would override what you set in the rewrite. There are some workarounds to that situation if you need them, but otherwise that should do it for you.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. I can't find the [B] flag documented anywhere. Can you explain it or point me to some info about it?

Comment: Oh, I actually thought it was just an oversight in the 2.0 documents, but looking at the source it really doesn't exist until Apache 2.2...so don't use that if your site is on 2.0. Anyway, it escapes backreferences, so that if for whatever reason you have `example.com/this&that`, you don't get `cat=this` and `that=` with the rewrite, since the ampersand will be encoded.